# convert doubles from a text file into a binary file

Tags: c++, parsing, binary, double, type-conversion

I have a text file full of numbers (from a molecular dynamics output, should be type `double`) divided in three columns and with thousands of lines like this:

```
    -11.979920  -13.987064   -0.608777
     -9.174895  -13.979109   -0.809622
```

I want to read all the numbers in the file, convert them to type `double` and then save them into a `binary` file.
I know that binary file is not recommended, but I want it to test compression algorithms with both file formats, i.e text and binary. I have tried with [Need to convert txt file into binary file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016262/need-to-convert-txt-file-into-binary-file-in-c) but I am not sure if is converting each number in its whole format: -11.275804 or if it is parsing each individual number: -1,1,2,7,5, etc..

Edit: Have been trying to convert a single double to binary and back, there are some problems. Here's the core code

```
    if( std::string(argv[1]) == "-2bin")  //convert to binary
{
    cout << "Performing the conversion: Text -> Binary..." << endl;
    std::ifstream in(argv[2]);
    std::ofstream out(argv[3], std::ios::binary);
    double d;

    while(in >> d) {
        cout << "read a double: "<< d <<endl;
        out.write((char*)&d, sizeof d);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    cout << "Conversion complete!" << endl;
    return 0;
}else if( std::string(argv[1]) == "-2text" ) //convert to text
{
    cout << "Performing the conversion: Binary -> Text..." << endl;
    std::ifstream in(argv[2], std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream  out(argv[3]);
    std::string s;

    while(in >> s) {
        cout << "read a string:" << s <<endl;
        out.write((char*)&s, s.length());
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    cout << "Conversion complete!" << endl;
    return 0;
```

When reading only one double, for example `1.23456789` the read string is just of length 7

```
read a double: 1.23457
```

I want it to read until the next 'space' and then do the conversion to double->bin.
When doing the binary -> text conversion everything is just broken, I don't know how to handle the binary and convert it to double and then string.

Update: Finally I managed to check that the binary conversion is working with `od -lF` utility, but every each line there is a strange line that I have no idea what it means, it cuts the zero from the first number and the output comes in two columns instead of 3:

```
od -lF composite_of10_2.bin | more
0000000     -4600438323394026364     -4599308401772716498
                       -11.97992               -13.987064
0000020     -4619713441568795935     -4602017412087121980
                       -0.608777                -9.174895
0000040     -4599312880039595965     -4617904390634477481
                      -13.979109                -0.809622
```

Does this look correctly converted? How should I perform the conversion from binary to double string?

Comment: You can easily check it by writing one number using the methods shown in the post you linked to and then read back the file one byte at a time. If the bytes read are the ASCII codes for the digits then it has not converted the number.

Comment: -1 because it seems the OP has not given this an honest effort.  @SamGamgee if you have indeed already tried, please edit the question to include more detail -- i.e. what have you done, what were the results, why were the results wrong -- and I will gladly remove the downvote.  I'd also suggest basic software engineering, like using really small test cases:  1) can you parse a single double correctly; 2) can you write a double to binary format correctly; 3) can you read a double from binary correctly, etc.

Comment: Ok I spent some more time trying to figure it out how it works, but so far this is what I was able to achieve. Added the code and the output to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your binary -> text conversion you read in the data as a 'string' while your binary file contains binary 'doubles'

```
std::string s;

    while(in >> s) { ...
```

This is going to give undefined results, you need to read in as 'double' and convert the value into a string, this will be handled natively by the text output stream

```
double d;
while( in.read( (char*)&d, sizeof(d) ) { //, Read the double value form the binary stream
    out << d << ' '; //< Write the double value to the output stream which is in text format
}
```

Comment: Ok makes sense! I tried but I found that `in >> d` is false it never enters the loop, then I tried `!in.eof()` and it gets into an infinite loop reading nothing, the binary file must be badly formatted..

Comment: EDIT; sorry, I made a typo, when reading from a binary stream you want to use .read( char*, int bytes)

Comment: Now it is working, thank you. Got the precision right with `ut << std::setprecision(12) << d << ' ';` but still one problem remains, I lost the configuration of the file: three doubles per line. Do I have to add the `\n` manually on the write to string after every three iterations?

Comment: I am marking this as an answer ;) If someone know how to resolve the line division please do tell.

Comment: You can write '\n' but a more standard method is std::endl (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/endl/) which will put the correct line ending on for whatever platform Unix/windows etc you are on

Comment: Thanks again. I added a counter and every three reads I do `endl(out)` and now the output is good.